# Any suggestion on how to model this?

Tags: modeling

i am modeling this cardbox but run into some problem with the curve pop out at the joint.
After tried some method, idont know how to model this perfectly. My way of doing it sucks.
[image: My approach]
[image: Cardbox]

Comment: Try to bevel the edge at the center. Ctrl+B.

Comment: @lemon Its not working, Cause there three edge connecting to this vertce.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you are asking for here. Is it the end of the box like this?

[image]

If so then I can make up some screenshots. If not then maybe you could describe it a bit more